# Objective C: Pass Result from Popup Window Back To Calling Class

Tags: objective-c, class, scope

I'm writing a very simple Mac OS app to parse a text only video EDL (edit decision list) and pull out locators (or 'markers' if you're familiar with Apple's FCP nomenclature) and add them to a new NSMutableArray to be displayed in an `NSTableView`.

All of this works perfectly, resulting in something similar to the following image for my test EDL:

[image: VFX Utility]

My ultimate goal is to further process this list and reduce it to only those markers which contain a video effect (VFX) name. Those are the RED markers in my sample. I want to be able to open a very simple pop-up window asking which color represents the VFX (again, RED in this case) so I can simply iterate thru the array and print those locators only.

I've created a new window and window controller to open the following window:

[image]
This works great, and I can use an NSLog within my new window controller class to display my typed responses.

The question then is: how do I pass my typed response back to my calling class, and then execute a new method to use this response for further processing of my array?

As it is now, when I hit the 'OK' button, it executes a method (in my new window controller class) which assigns the text in my `NSTextField` to a new `NSString`. But how can I then ALSO pass that variable back AND execute another method in the original calling class which holds my EDL array?

I'm sorry for the newbie question, and I'm not asking somebody to actually write code for me, but I don't even know what to look for in the manuals to study up on this. I'm a video editor first and a coder only as a hobby, so go easy on me please.

Thank you, btw, to Phillip Mills for helping me get as far as I have with the TableView.